# jquery ui-tab, how to do this - page url with passing values

Tags: jquery

I been sending countless days trying to figure this out from multiple code sources.

I would like to start with fresh code.

I would like to use the ui tab feature but also have the tab pages accessible by url. In addition, I wanted to be able to pass values by string in the url (ie ?Mode=Apple). My send result was that I want to visit (www.something.com/#Tab1_MONKEYSEE?Mode=Apple&Money=King) - send me to the tab1 page and pass those values.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really specific, i can start helping you by pointing out this very useful function that retrieve a parameter from the querystring::

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

So if you navigate to a page www.something.com/yourpage.php?tab=Tab1_MONKEYSEE&Mode=Apple&Money=King you could do:

```
var tab = getParameterByName('tab');
var mode = getParameterByName('mode');
var Money = getParameterByName('Money');

var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();

$tabs.tabs('select', '#' + tab);//select tabs with id: Tab1_MONKEYSEE
```

Comment: that is awesome, this is something i never thought about!